# How to use the filter plugin of jQuery tablesorter with cells containing HTML elements?

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm trying to use the filter plugin of the tablesorter plugin with cells containing html elements. Unfortunately that doesn't work out well. All I got is one entry in the filter list with every select option concatenated. I've tried to add a custom textExtraction function, but that doesn't change anything. An example of my code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMzNf/10/
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 2.4, I've added a `filter_useParsedData` option which forces the filter widget to use parsed data for the entire table, or you can just add a class name of `filter-parsed` to the table header to target a single column.

Get more details about how to use this option in the [documentation](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-useParsedData). Also check out [this issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/149) - it shows that you can use the textExtraction function to control the parsed data.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome support. I've seen that flag, but didn't understand what it does. Any ideas why the strings are changed to lower case before added to the filter dropdown list? Not that big deal though. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMzNf/11/

Comment: @iamtimeshift that would be the [`ignoreCase` option](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#ignorecase) in action :)